# How to process 3rd party dependency's CSS in a Create React App application

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I'm making a web application based on `CRA 3.4.1` with a component library `PrimeReact 4.1.2`.

My own **CSS** gets processed thanks to CRA's PostCSS setup, e.g. each `display: flex` in the sources gets the prefixed `-ms-flexbox` version added in the built files (`main.<hash>.chunk.css`), enabling `IE10` support.

The problem is **PrimeReact** components have their own **CSS** bundled, and this **CSS** does not get processed when I'm building my app. As a result, the built `2.<hash>.chunk.css` doesn't have the vendor prefixed rules.

How do I enable the processing of such 3rd party CSS? Preferably without ejecting. Can it be configured? I don't see anything about this in the official docs.
Maybe there is a way to exclude 3rd party **CSS**, and then I'll just `import '../node_modules/primereact/resources/primereact.css'` to have it processed as my own CSS?

Comment: I've created https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/1312 , but even if they add their own processing, there is no guarantee that they'd target the same browsers I need.

Comment: Just include import their css into your code, and it should work, I believe. They also mention that in their documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/primereact

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov please check my new answer. This is a specific `primereact` issue due to the `package.json` `browserslist` option.

Comment: @ChristosLytras, very interesting, thanks for figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a specific issue of [primereact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/primereact) package and it happens because inside [`package.json`](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/master/package.json#L58) there is a `browserslist` rule for `"not ie <= 11"`:

```json
"browserslist": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not ie <= 11",
  "not op_mini all"
]
```

You'll have to hardcode the file inside `node_modules/primereact/package.json` and change `"not ie <= 11"` to `"ie 10-11"`. [PostCSS Normalize](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-normalize) does not add borwser prefixes for **IE11** so you'll have to set a `browserslist` value of `ie 10-11`.

After that change you'll have all `primereact/resources/primereact.css` rules to generate `-ms-flex` prefixes.

I'm not sure if that is a real [primereact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/primereact) issue; if they don't or they can't support **IE11**, then it's not an issue because their `package.json` is strict to that rule not supporting **IE11**.

You can use [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to create a patch and apply that fix/change after each `npm`/`yarn` modification (*be careful as it does exclude `package.json` by default*).

So, normally [CRA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) and [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) do add the prefixes for browser if you setup `"browserslist"` inside your project `package.json` but [PostCSS Normalize](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-normalize) does check each module `package.json` and overrides the default project settings. If you face again such issues, you first go and check the contents of the regarding module `package.json` file and specifically for the `"browserslist"` option.

Comment: Completely forgot about this, but yes, I'm already importing the CSS exactly like this. The build system somehow detects (?) it coming from a dependency, and doesn't process it. Also tried importing `primereact.css` instead of `primereact.min.css` - still no processing, other than minifying it.

Comment: It does process it, it bundles all CSS together. How can you tell it doesn't process it? You can also see some details about CSS modules in the [CRA > Adding a CSS Modules Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) page. Do you maybe have a repository that I can check why it's not working?

Comment: As the question says, CSS is bundled into 2 separate files: mine into `main.<hash>.chunk.css`, dependencies' into `2.<hash>.chunk.css`. Mine gets processed, the other doesn't. I can tell, because the same rule gets vendor prefixed version prepended in one file, but not the other. I don't have a repository. Not sure how CSS modules are relevant here.

Comment: Every CSS that's beeing imported is considered a CSS module and that's what we're doing here, we're importing CSS. I understand your problem and I think it has nothing to do with PrimeReact but how CRA Webpack config handles CSS modules importing from  `node_modules`; so maybe there is an exclude rule for just CSS modules that are imported from any `node_modules` location. I'll check that if maybe it's the case here.

Comment: `Every CSS that's beeing imported is considered a CSS module` - that's not what your link says. I'm not using CSS modules, PrimeReact doesn't as well - just regular stylesheets without local scoping.

Comment: That's what is saying exactly *"A CSS Module is a CSS file in which all class names and animation names are scoped locally by default. All URLs (url(...)) and @imports are in module request format (./xxx and ../xxx means relative, xxx and xxx/yyy means in modules folder, **i. e. in node_modules**)."* if you follow this link inside it [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). You seem to be more interesting on arguing than focusing on the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to figure things out. Thank you for trying to help.